# Elasticsearch results sort order

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get results in a specific order first get the exact phrase (match_phrase) match and then match any word in phrase (match), for example, if I'm searching for "where can i find my account"I will get the documents containing the full phrase "where can I find my account" first and then documents that contain one or more of the words "where", "can", "find", "my", "account"

my query :

```
GET my_index/_search

{

"query": {

"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "match": {"body": "right usage of Localization"      }
    } ,
    {
      "match": {"title": "right usage of Localization"      }
    } 
    ],
    "should": [
    {
      "match_phrase": {"body": "translated"      }
    },
    {
      "match_phrase": {"title": "translated"      }
    } 
    ]
  }
```

} 
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boost query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html) to boost the documents matching your match_phrase query.
You can change the boost parameter accordingly.

Following query should work for you

```
POST phrase_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "title": "this is where it should work first"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "body": "this is where it should work first"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "title": {
                    "query": "this is where it should work first",
                    "boost": 20
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "body": {
                    "query": "this is where it should work first",
                    "boost": 20
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! What if I just wanted to use only the `match_phrase` for both fields? I tried your answer without any of the `match` but it did not work for me.

Comment: what ES version are you using?